# Время кеширования запросов влияет на бизнес-логику. Что делать?

Tags: php, проектирование, doctrine, спецификация

Проблема до безумия проста, но адекватного решения я не вижу.

У меня есть сущность Новость.

У новости, кроме всего прочего, есть свойство **Дата публикации** *(date_publication)* определяющие можно ли показывать новость. То есть дата, после которой новость можно опубликовать на сайте.

Это основное бизнес правило/ограничение.

Соответственно, при выводе списка новостей я должен сравнивать **Дату  публикации** с текущим временем и тут я сталкиваюсь с проблемой кэширования.

Все мы знаем что запросы использующие текущее время не кешируются. Например MySQL не кеширует запросы в которых используется функция `NOW()` или `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`. Поэтому мне нужно в явном виде передавать текущую дату:

```
date_publication <= "2017-04-10 13:50:00"
```

Новости это такой контент, который как правило обновляется не часто, особенно на ресурсах где новости являются не корневым контекстом *(Сore Сontext)*.

Я хочу кешировать на 10 минут запрос к БД который возвращает список новостей. И для того, что бы это работало мне не достаточно просто сказать - кэшируй этот запрос на 10 минут. Тут я упираюсь в целый ряд ограничений:

- Я использую для доступа к БД [Doctrine](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/);
- Я использую стандартную функцию `setResultCacheLifetime()` из Doctrine для кеширования [результатов запросов](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/caching.html#result-cache), которая автоматически генерит ID кеша на основе параметров запроса;
- Можно конечно в явном виде указать ID кеша `setResultCacheId()`, но это влечет к переусложнению и фактически реализации почти тойже функциональности что и по умолчанию;
- *Вместо Doctrine здесь может выступать любой движок БД поддерживающий кешировани запросов. Я привел Doctrine как пример;*
- *Под капотом все запросы кешируются в Redis;*
- Бизнес логика требует чтоб я сравнивал реально, текущее время, но в этом случае ID кеша будет меняться каждую секунду и кеш в результате работать не будет.

Я задавал [этот вопрос](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/6387) Doctrine и мне дали понять, что это не их забота и решатся эта задача должна на другом уровне. **И вот я пытаюсь понять, на каком же именно уровне должна решатся эта задача**. Прошу мне в этом помочь.

Собственно, решением этой задачи будет округлить текущее время до времени кеширования:

```
$now = new \DateTime();
// округляем дату вниз чтоб в выборку не попали данные которых там быть не должно
$now->setTimestamp(floor($now->getTimestamp() / $cacheLifetime) * $cacheLifetime);
```

Но в этом случае:

1. Текущее время оказывается не настоящим, а бизнес требует чтоб описывая ограничения мы использовали настоящее время;
2. Для округления мы должны использовать время кеширования запроса и должны указывать его дважды *(или дважды использовать)*;
3. Если при описании бизнес правила мы используем текущую дату, то непонятно в какой момент мы должны округлять дату в запросе.

Для описания бизнес правил я использую шаблон проектирования [Спецификация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)). И спецификация, описывающая нужное ограничение, может быть сложным агрегатом в котором правило проверки **Даты публикации** может быть зарыто очень глубоко. И вытащить его от туда, чтоб округлить дату, может быть очень не просто.

Чтоб понимать как это может выглядеть, опишу пример использования спецификации:

```
$result = $rep->match(
    new AndX(
        new NewsPublished(),
        new Slice($slice_size, $slice_number)
    ),
    new Cache(600)
);
```

что разворачивается в:

```
$result = $rep->match(
    new AndX(
        new Equals('enabled', true),
        new LessOrEqualThan('date_publication', new \DateTime()),
        new Limit($slice_size),
        new Offset(($slice_number - 1) * $slice_size)
    ),
    new Cache(600)
);
```

Есть мысль, что округление должно выполнятся в функции `match()`, которая разбирает спецификации и собирает на их основе SQL запрос. Для применения спецификаций, я использую стороннюю библиотеку и ее автор со мной [не согласен](https://github.com/Happyr/Doctrine-Specification/pull/146).

И вообще, кеширование это про доступ к данным *(Persistence Layer)* и не должно пересекаться с доменным уровнем *(Domain Layer)*.

И вот уже несколько дней я сижу и думаю. А как же правильней? Понятно что костыль подоткнуть не проблема, а правильно то как? Так чтоб код был ясный и прозрачный, легко читаемый, без костылей и соответствовал единому языку *(Ubiquitous Language)*.

Comment: так тут несколько путей:
1. Отказаться от кэширования.
2. Сбрасывать кэшь после изменений.
3. выбирать всё и рендерить на уровне php

Comment: @Naumov 1. на highload без кеширования нельзя. 2. это дата публикации. Изменение происходит по времени, а не по действию от пользователя. 3. Это вообще жесть. А если новостей 100500? Вы все в память грузить будете? Пожалейте железку

Comment: доктрина на хайлоаде? хотел бы я посмотреть на запросы, которые она генерит, и их план. выше правильно заметили - кэшируй всё, а решение об отображении принимай на уровне сервиса, там где бизнес-логика. от себя добавлю: кэш имеет право жить, пока живы и не менялись данные, которые в нём хранятся. вполне можно для каждой новости сделать отдельный кэш сущности и один небольшой кэш списка новостей "ид+дата". его обновляй, его фильтруй в коде, нужные айтемы новостей вынимай отдельно после этого. недостающие добавляй в кэш.

Comment: @Lexx918 зря ты так про доктрину. Запросы более чем оптимальные. Вариант с "кешируй все и разбирай на клиенте" не подойдет если у тебя много сущностей. Просто в память процесса могут не влезть. С хранением списка "ид+дата" та же проблема. Если записей меньше 100, то ок, если несколько тысяч и тебе нужно вывести 6 записей с каким-то сдвигом, то это получается очень не быстро проще дернуть СУБД. Можно конечно хранить кеш для конкретных срезок выборок, но тогда сбрасывать кеш по изменению будет накладно.

Comment: @ghost404 можно вообще не хранить кэш каждой новости, если у тебя InnoDB в мускуле. поставь старый добрый HandlerSocket или лучше настрой доступ по мемкешовому протоколу и первичным ключам, и просто ходи в таблицу мимо мускульного демона. это так же быстро, как юзать кэш. хранить 1000 и 5000 записей "ид+дата" в памяти - вообще не проблема.

Comment: @ghost404, глупый вопрос: а если по спецификации раз в секунду(условно) обновлять у новости флаг "показывать", а при выборке выбирать только те, у которых уже установлен этот флаг?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev кто-то уже предлагал такое решение. Только дергать нужно раз в минуту. Проблема в том что в 99% случаев мы будем за зря дергать базу каждую минуту. Решением было бы что-то типа никсовой команды `at`

Comment: Ну почему за зря? Таким образом и требования бизнеса удовлетворены, и система работает производительно и кэш в норме. Ну а сам параметр времени между обновлением можно обсудить с бизнесом в виде: "_Зависимость нагрузки на базу данных от максимального отклонения времени появления новости_". В таком виде это уже будет бизнес проблема, а не техническая :)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev *"Зависимость нагрузки на базу данных от максимального отклонения времени появления новости"* - нет этой зависимости. Либо мы дергаем бд каждую минуту, либо нет. Если у нас нет отложенных новостей, мы все равно должны дергать бд на случае если такие появятся. Да, можно написать прослойку чтоб дергать например Redis, а не базу. А базу дергать только тогда когда это действительно необходимо, но суть от этого не поменяется. Все равно будем дергать систему в 99% случаев в холостую.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Реальный профит можно получить только если вынести обновление по крону на отдельную ноду и тогда нагрузка на ней не будет влият на read ноду. И нужно максимально ограничить влияние write ноды на БД которую использует read нода. Условно read читает с реплики основной БД которая стоит на write ноде или вообще на отдельной ноде.

Comment: @ghost404, так можно дергать не каждую минуту а раз в две минуты. Или даже раз в пять. А бизнесу сказать, что если мы будем обновлять статус новостей раз в минуту, то нагрузка будет такая-то, а если раз в пять минут, то нагрузка будет такая-то. И пусть уже бизнес решает, что критичнее, делать по запросу в минуту (и выделять соответствующие вычислительные мощности под это) или мириться с задержкой в публикации.